# fb like box intermittently does not load, tried everything

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-likebox

I'm trying get the Facebook Like box to show up on my site. So far, I haven't found anyone describe a problem quite like mine here. There appears to be some kind of pattern, but I can't figure out what it is. Here's what I have observed:

- It does not matter if FB user is logged in or not. The box sometimes loads when logged in and sometimes when not and visa versa. There are no special demographics set for the page.
- The browser does not matter, though Safari gets way more consistently working results than Chrome. Chrome, however, works almost every time so long as it's in Incognito.
- It doesn't matter whether I use HTML5 or XFBML. Both produce the same results. And the IFRAME doesn't work at all--it only shows a little like button.

I've tried all the solutions I could find for problems like mine, but none of the solutions have made any impact on this.

This is what I've added immediately after opening the body tag:

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=408273115919487";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

This was added immediately after opening the head tag:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

This is what I placed to show the like box:

```
<fb:like-box href="https://www.facebook.com/petruzzophotography" width="292" height="200" colorscheme="light" show_faces="true" header="false" stream="false" show_border="false"></fb:like-box>
```

This is working in a Wordpress environment, so it's possible that I've got some conflicting plugins or something. I've already disabled non-essentials without any success.

Can anyone recommend what to do next?

Comment: If you provide an example of the entire page's markup, it might help. You definitely shouldn't have `<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">` inside the `<head>` element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I find Facebook Like Box to be very glitchy and I stopped using it. I started using:

Facebook Members Widget - http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-members/

I hope this helps!